# .net Maui Not Binding many to many to same table in Picker

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, maui, picker, .net-8.0

I'm creating an app to register Teams for Sportstatistics. In this case I need a View (MVVM) to select two teams and assign the results of a game. The first part of the view (the collectionview) works as expected. My current games show up in the left pane. On the right side is form to add new games and to edit a selected game. My teams are showing up in the pickers but the problem is my View is not showing the selected team in the Picker after selecting an game on the left side.

This is the View:

```
    <Grid RowDefinitions="*" ColumnDefinitions="*, *">
        <CollectionView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Games}" EmptyView="No items to display" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGame}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Games">
                    <VerticalStackLayout Padding="5">
                        <Label FontSize="14">
                            <Label.Text>
                                <MultiBinding StringFormat="- {0:d}: {1} - {3} ({2}-{4})">
                                    <Binding Path="Date"/>
                                    <Binding Path="Team1.Name" />
                                    <Binding Path="ResultTeam1" />
                                    <Binding Path="Team2.Name" />
                                    <Binding Path="ResultTeam2" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Label.Text>
                        </Label>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

        <ActivityIndicator IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Center" Color="{StaticResource Primary}" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" />
            
        <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Spacing="10">
            <Picker Title="Team 1" ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGame.Team1}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            <Picker Title="Team 2" ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGame.Team2}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            <Label Text="Result team 1" />
            <Entry Placeholder="Result team 1" Text="{Binding SelectedGame.ResultTeam1}" />
            <Label Text="Result team 2" />
            <Entry Placeholder="Result team 2" Text="{Binding SelectedGame.ResultTeam2}" />
  
            <HorizontalStackLayout Spacing="10">
                <Button Text="Add" Command="{Binding AddCommand}"/>
                <Button Text="Edit" Command="{Binding EditCommand}"/>
                <Button Text="Deselect" Command="{Binding DeselectCommand}"/>
            </HorizontalStackLayout>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
```

ViewModel:

```
    public partial class GameViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        public ObservableCollection<Game> games;

        [ObservableProperty]
        public ObservableCollection<Team> teams;


        [ObservableProperty]
        public Game selectedGame;

        private TeamRepository _teamRepository;
        private GameRepository _gameRepository;

        public GameViewModel(TeamRepository teamRepository, GameRepository gameRepository)
        {
            _teamRepository = teamRepository;
            _gameRepository = gameRepository;

            RefreshGames();
            Teams= new ObservableCollection<Team>(_teamRepository.GetTeams());

            SelectedGame = new Game();
            Title = "Games";
        }

        private void RefreshGames()
        {
            Games= new ObservableCollection<Game>(_gameRepository.GetGames());
        }
...
```

Game Class

```
    public class Game
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Team1Id { get; set; }
        public int Team2Id { get; set; }
        public Team Team1 { get; set;}
        public Team Team2 { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Date{ get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public int ResultTeam1 { get; set; }
        public int ResultTeam2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Using this methods I succesfully created Views where my data is retrieved and shown in the Picker after selecting an item on the left side.

This View features selecting two teams from the same entity. And somehow .net Maui does not compute.

The selectedItem returns my object correct but my pickers remains blank. The Entries for the results are filled in properly.

I was expecting to see my SelectedGame.Teams in the Pickers.

Got any ideas?

Comment: Please post the Game class

Comment: in Edited version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're binding models, you have to add Equals in the model for proper binding.

Model Team.cs:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
   return obj is Team team && Id == team.Id;
}
```

That does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you provided, I created new demo and tried to achieve the functionality.

You can refer to the following code:

**GameViewModel.cs**

```
public  class GameViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Game> Games { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }

        private Game _selectedGame;
        public Game SelectedGame
        {
            get { return _selectedGame; }
            set {
                SetProperty(ref _selectedGame, value);
                // update the selectedTeam for the two pickers on the right
                UpdateTheSelectedTeamsForPickker(SelectedGame);
            }
        }

        private Team _selectedTeam1;
        public Team SelectedTeam1
        {
            get { return _selectedTeam1; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _selectedTeam1, value); }
        }

        private Team _selectedTeam2;
        public Team SelectedTeam2
        {
            get { return _selectedTeam2; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _selectedTeam2, value); }
        }

        public GameViewModel()
        {

            RefreshGames();

            Teams = new ObservableCollection<Team>();
            Teams.Add(new Team {  Name ="test_team1"} );
            Teams.Add(new Team {  Name ="test_team2"} );
            Teams.Add(new Team {  Name ="test_team3"} );


            // SelectedGame = new Game();
            SelectedGame = Games[1];

            // update the selectedTeam for the two pickers on the right
            UpdateTheSelectedTeamsForPickker(SelectedGame);
        }

        private void UpdateTheSelectedTeamsForPickker(Game selectedGame) {
            for ( int i=0;i< Teams.Count;i++) {
                Team team = Teams[i];
                if (team.Name == selectedGame.Team1.Name) {
                    SelectedTeam1 = Teams[i];
                }

                if (team.Name == selectedGame.Team2.Name)
                {
                    SelectedTeam2 = Teams[i];
                }
            }
        }

        private void RefreshGames()
        {
           // Games = new ObservableCollection<Game>(_gameRepository.GetGames());
           Games = new ObservableCollection<Game>();
           Games.Add(new Game {  Date = "2024-2-4", Team1 = new Team {  Name = "test_team1" }, Team2 = new Team { Name = "test_team3" }, ResultTeam1 ="win",ResultTeam2 = " failed" });
           Games.Add(new Game {  Date = "2024-2-5", Team1 = new Team {  Name = "test_team2" }, Team2 = new Team { Name = "test_team3" } , ResultTeam1 = "failed", ResultTeam2 = " win" });

        }

        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

**Game.cs**

```
public  class Game: INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       public string Date { get; set; }

       private Team _team1;
       public Team Team1
       {
           get { return _team1; }
           set { SetProperty(ref _team1, value); }
       }

       private Team _team2;
       public Team Team2
       {
           get { return _team2; }
           set { SetProperty(ref _team2, value); }
       }

       public string ResultTeam1 { get; set; }

       public string ResultTeam2 { get; set; }


       bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
       {
           if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
               return false;
           storage = value;
           OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
           return true;
       }
       protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
       {
           PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
       }
       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   }
```

**Team.cs**

```
public partial class Team: INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       private string _name;
       public string Name
       {
           get { return _name; }
           set { SetProperty(ref _name, value); }
       }

       bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
       {
           if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
               return false;
           storage = value;
           OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
           return true;
       }
       protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
       {
           PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
       }
       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   }
```

**Note:**

1.If we want to set the `SelectedItem` for the Picker, we should set an object from the `ItemsSource` not another object(e.g. `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGame.Team1}"` or `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGame.Team2}"`).

So, we can add two new selected items on `GameViewModel.cs` for the two pickers on the right and update the two variables while we change the `SelectedGame`:

```
    private Team _selectedTeam1;
    public Team SelectedTeam1
    {
        get { return _selectedTeam1; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _selectedTeam1, value); }
    }

    private Team _selectedTeam2;
    public Team SelectedTeam2
    {
        get { return _selectedTeam2; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _selectedTeam2, value); }
    }
```

And we can update above two selected items for the two Pickers as follows:

```
    private void UpdateTheSelectedTeamsForPickker(Game selectedGame) {
        for ( int i=0;i< Teams.Count;i++) {
            Team team = Teams[i];
            if (team.Name == selectedGame.Team1.Name) {
                SelectedTeam1 = Teams[i];
            }

            if (team.Name == selectedGame.Team2.Name)
            {
                SelectedTeam2 = Teams[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i'm looking for another solution with the communitytoolkit.mvvm. For clarification: in other views this method works fine. The objects in the ObservableCollection Teams is of type Team and so is the type of my SelectedGame.Team1 of SelectedGame.Team2. As long as the types of the SelectedItem and the Array in the Picker are the same, my solution should have worked.